# scroll background while foreground objects stay static in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have `scrollable custom view`. It's working well.

I want to be able to add a `horizontal LinearLayout` in the `foreground of that view`. Very importantly, I want the `LinearLayout` to stay static as the `custom view is scrolled`.

So basically, how would I do that? Normally, when I have a foreground view, the moment I click the background, the `foreground disappears` (I usually use `Dialog` for the `foreground`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap everything in a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`. Make sure your foreground object is the last item in the layout so it acts as an overlay.