# Tracking scrolling tableRows with respect to a LinearLayout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

Inside a RelativeLayout; I have a TableLayout in a ScrollView, and a horizontal LinearLayout. My view is working fine: as the table scrolls in the background, the LinearLayout is static in the foreground. What I now need, is to know exactly where the table and the LinearLayout are intersecting during scrolling.

Since the LinearLayout is static, I know where it is at all time, say y=50pixel. Supposing I have TextViews inside the TableLayout. So as the table scrolls, I want to know which TextView (i.e. tableRow) is intersecting/hidden by the LinearLayout.

Comment: for some background see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950082/scroll-background-while-foreground-objects-stay-static-in-android

Comment: It's also a good answer if all I get is whether a TableRow is above or below the line.

Comment: Can you post your layout file? And if possible, add the code where you inflate/initialize this view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `View.getLocationOnScreen()` on the table rows?

Comment: Yes. And I have also already tried everything here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619693/getting-views-coordinates-relative-to-the-root-layout. I use a for-loop to do `.getChildAt(i)` for each TableRow. They all return 130 as their yOffset

Answer (score 0):

> I have a horizontal line at y-offset = 310 pixel. As I scroll my
>   tableLayout, which is inside a ScrollView, I want to know which row of
>   the table is intersecting my horizontal line.

You could use the [`View.getLocationInWindow()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow%28int%5B%5D%29) method. Initially you'd need to see which row intersects the line and then using a custom `ScrollView`, follow the scrolling:

```
// in the onCreate:
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    int[] loc = new int[2];
                    ll.getLocationInWindow(loc);
                    scrollView.setYIntersection(loc[1]);
                    ViewGroup table = (ViewGroup) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
                    // find out which row initially intersects our line so
                    // we can initialize mCrossedRow and position
                    for (int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++) {
                        final View row = table.getChildAt(i);
                        row.getLocationInWindow(loc);
                        if (loc[1] <= scrollView.getYIntersection()
                                && loc[1] + row.getHeight() >= scrollView
                                        .getYIntersection()) {
                            scrollView.setCurrIntersection(row, i);
                            row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    scrollView.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                }
            });
```

With the custom `ScrollView` being:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    /**
     * This will be the current intersected row.
     */
    private View mCrossedRow;
    /**
     * The row position of the intersected row, mCrossedRow.
     */
    private int mRowOrder;
    /**
     * The y value of the intersecting line.
     */
    private int mLine;
    /**
     * Used as a temporary holder for the location retrieval.
     */
    private int[] mLocHelper = new int[2];

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setYIntersection(int y) {
        mLine = y;
    }

    public int getYIntersection() {
        return mLine;
    }

    public void setCurrIntersection(View row, int childPosition) {
        mCrossedRow = row;
        mRowOrder = childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        // this will be called every time the user scrolls so we need to
        // keep updating the position and see if the crossed row still
        // intersects the line otherwise move it to the next row.
        mCrossedRow.getLocationInWindow(mLocHelper);
        if (mLocHelper[1] <= mLine
                && mLocHelper[1] + mCrossedRow.getHeight() >= mLine) {
            // do nothing, we're still in the same row
        } else {
            if (t - oldt > 0) {
                // going down so increase the row position
                mRowOrder++;
            } else {
                // going up so decrease the row position
                mRowOrder--;
            }
            // visual effect, the intersecting row will have a red
            // background and all other rows will have a white background.
            // You could setup a listener here to get notified that a new
            // row intersects the line.
            mCrossedRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            mCrossedRow = ((ViewGroup) getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(mRowOrder);
            mCrossedRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
}
```